# Saber os dados do input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá, preciso saber qual é o tipo de dado que esta sendo inserido no input do HTML, tenho que saber se o que está la é texto(string) ou se é um número. E depois eu crio um vetor usando o slipt. Ele sempre está retornando Número

```
let valores = $('#valores').val();
if(isNaN(valores) === true){      
    console.log('Número');
} else {
    console.log('Letra');
}
let dados = valores.split(';');
```

Comment: Olá de uma lida neste link talvez seja uma luz para sua dúvida, tente editar seu post e acrescentar mais detalhes. desde já boa sorte! https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/537487-como-verificar-tipo-de-valor-inserido-no-input/

Comment: Quais os valores que vc usou pra testar? Se vc vai fazer o split depois, então não vai ter só números, por favor edite a pergunta e coloque as strings que está usando e qual deveria ser o resultado

Comment: Matheus, você percebe que `NaN` significa "Not a Number"? Ou seja, seu `if` faz "Se `valores` não é um número, logar 'Número'"... Não faz sentido

Answer (score 1):

**Tente o código abaixo:**

```js
var myVar = prompt("Digite um texto ou número.");

if(!myVar){
alert("Operação cancelada pelo usuário");
}
else{

while(myVar.trim().length == 0){
myVar = prompt("Digite um texto ou um número.");
}

if(!isNaN(myVar)){
alert(myVar + " é um número");
}
else{
alert(myVar + " é uma String");
}
}
```

Comment: Execute o código novamente.